# How Jmeter distributes the internet speed among various threads?

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing

- I have a client requirement for generating a load of 100 users. Those 100 users have an average internet speed of 20 Mbps.
- The machine on which I am planning to run JMeter in non-GUI mode has an internet bandwidth of 100 Mbps.

So, is this feasible to generate a load of 100 users/threads with each having 20 Mbps internet speed considering, we have a total bandwidth of 100Mbps only.

Or

Please suggest an alternative solution for this problem statement.

Comment: This might help : https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-simulate-different-network-speeds-your-jmeter-load-test/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If an average user has bandwidth of 20 Mbps and your machine's maximum is 100 Mbps - you will be able to only simulate 100 / 20 = 5 virtual users **given your load test fully utilizes bandwidth of the user/machine**

It might be the case you can still conduct the load testing for more virtual users using this machine as:

1. Real users don't hammer the application under test "non-stop", they need some time to "think" between operations so consider adding reasonable [Timers](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#timers) to introduce realistic delays between the requests
2. The absolute majority of bandwidth is consumed via so called "embedded resources": images, scripts, styles, sounds, fonts, etc. Real browsers download these embedded resources, but they do this **only once** so you need to add [HTTP Cache Manager](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Cache_Manager) to properly simulate this behaviour.
3. Once you come up with the realistic version of your test scenario you can measure the bandwidth consumed by 1 virtual user via [Bytes Throughput Over Time](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/BytesThroughput/) and see how much spare bandwidth is left using [PerfMon Plugin](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/PerfMon/)

   - if there will be sufficient bandwidth left for 100 users - you should be good to go
   - if not - you will have to find another machine(s) and [run your JMeter test in Distributed Mode](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-perform-distributed-testing-in-jmeter/)